# How to addClass and removeClass to child element when aria true or false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation, font-awesome

I'm using the [dropdown button by Zurb Foundation 5](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/dropdown_buttons.html) with font awesome and the idea is to rotate the font when the menu is visible, and rotate it back once its hidden.

Zurb foundation 5 does not use class open on the element so hasClass doesn't work, instead it uses Aria and since hasAria doesn't exist I've tried to use some solutions that sadly don't work in one way or more. What I'm trying to do is add the class `fa-rotate-90` to the font element `<i>` when the parent `.wf-burger` is `aria-expanded = true` and remove it when `aria-expanded = false`.

*Here is my rather simple HTML code:*

```
<h1>
    <a aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="drop1" data-dropdown="drop1" href="#" class="wf-burger">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-bars fa-rotate-90"></i>
    </a>
</h1> 
<ul aria-hidden="true" class="f-dropdown" id="drop1" data-dropdown-content>
    <li><a title="Link 1" href="#1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a title="Link 2" href="#2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a title="Link 3" href="#3">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a title="Link 4" href="#4">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a title="Link 5" href="#5">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

*This code works but doesn't remove the class once the aria is false:*

```
(function($) {
    var attr = $('.wf-burger').attr('aria-expanded');
    if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
            $('.fa.fa-bars').addClass('fa-rotate-90');
    }
    if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== true) {
        $('.fa.fa-bars').removeClass('fa-rotate-90');
    }
})(jQuery);
```

*This code didn't work at all:*

```
(function($) {
    if ($('.wf-burger').attr('aria-expanded') === 'true') {
        $('.fa.fa-bars').addClass('fa-rotate-90');
    }
    if ($('.wf-burger').attr('aria-expanded') === 'false') {
        $('.fa.fa-bars').removeClass('fa-rotate-90');
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: or simply `if(!attr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more simpler solution would be to simply toggle the class on click.

```
$(".wf-burger").click(function(){
   $('.wf-burger .fa').toggleClass('fa-rotate-90');
});
```

**CSS solution**

I have just checked that it uses the open class when dropdown is opened, it is not working on docs, but it is working on the CodePen example, where I used the foundation **5.5.3** version.
http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.js

```
.wf-burger.open .fa{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

see example: http://codepen.io/shoaibik/pen/xVevrv

**Updated Answer:**

The issue was that the dropdown should be sibling of the anchor which is attached to the dropdown, if you remove the H1 tag it should work.

```
<a aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="drop1" data-dropdown="drop1" href="#" class="wf-burger">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-bars fa-rotate-90"></i>
</a>
<ul aria-hidden="true" class="f-dropdown" id="drop1" data-dropdown-content>
    <li><a title="Link 1" href="#1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a title="Link 2" href="#2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a title="Link 3" href="#3">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a title="Link 4" href="#4">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a title="Link 5" href="#5">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I did think of this solution and while its good for some instances in this case its not because clicking off any other element asides `.wf-burger` closes the element and that would mean that the toggle would still be active.

Comment: @SimonHayter I have updated the solution, it looks there is diff between the GitHub files and foundation CDN files. Did you used foundation from GitHub?

Comment: How do you know that it is version 5.5.3 on the cdn? since there's no versioning on it.

Comment: search 5.5.3 in the JavaScript source file and you will get it, it is mentioned there.

Comment: It's odd and confusing which I should be using since both are marked 5.5.3 but have differences.

Comment: yes, and the GitHub file has code for active class, see https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zurb/foundation-sites/v5/js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js

Comment: Well, what's even more odd is that I've updated the foundation use the same one as you've used in the Codepen and it doesn't add the open, see https://www.blackforce.co.uk (click the hamburger on the top left) in source the foundation is listed as foundation.min.js but is the same as that on the codepen..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112051/discussion-between-shoaib-iqbal-and-simon-hayter).

Comment: Thanks for spending the time helping me, this worked wonderfully ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this. You just need to use `$('.wf-burger').attr('aria-expanded') == 'true'`. No need to use the type check `===`.

Also using `toggleClass()` will be a good way for this.

```js
$('.fa.fa-bars').toggleClass(
    'fa-rotate-90', 
    $('.wf-burger').attr('aria-expanded') == 'true'
);
```

```css
.fa-rotate-90 {
  border:1px solid red;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="drop1" data-dropdown="drop1" href="#" class="wf-burger">
  <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-bars fa-rotate-90"></i>
</a>
<ul aria-hidden="true" class="f-dropdown" id="drop1" data-dropdown-content>
  <li><a title="Link 1" href="#1">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a title="Link 2" href="#2">Link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a title="Link 3" href="#3">Link 3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a title="Link 4" href="#4">Link 4</a>
  </li>
  <li><a title="Link 5" href="#5">Link 5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sadly doesn't work even the run code snippet doesn't either.